# How to stub a ruby class method in a module (Stripe gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have following api call to a Stripe method, belonging to a class that belongs to a module:

```
Stripe::Customer.list(email: current_email)
```

I want to mock the method `list` for any instance of `Customer` class. I tried this first:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:list).and_return([])
```

But I get:

```
1) {:Admin=>Admin::Turnover::BarPresenter, :type=>:model} #specs does something
     Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:list).and_return([])
       Stripe::Customer does not implement #list
```

Not sure why it says `not implement #list` when this is exactly what I am mocking.

Comment: This isn't really a Stripe question, just a ruby mocking question. Maybe this will help? https://github.com/stripe-ruby-mock/stripe-ruby-mock

Answer (score 0):

By calling `Stripe::Customer.list` you call a class method. You can stub `list` method of `Stripe::Customer` like this `allow(Stripe::Customer).to receive(:list).and_return([])`.